# Android - Download File From The Internet to SDCard - Safest Approach

Tags: java, android, download

I'm developing an APP that needs to download a file from the Internet and store it on the SDCard.
I've noticed that some devices report errors while downloading, such as "Parsing Error". I'm assuming that some devices don't have SDCard or the path that I'm getting in my class isn't correct. What's the safest approach to support all devices if there's no SDCard or isn't mounted ?
This is my code:

```
/**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/file.apk");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
```

I think the problem may be on this line:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/file.apk");
```

Should I use the **getExternalStorageDirectory() and download** ? or is there any "safest" location that is common to all devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want to use AsyncTask to download a file.  Because if the user kills that screen that hosts the Task, the download will be killed too.  Look into IntentService.

Second, familiarize yourself with the Android code examples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

You can check for what's available and then get the appropriate directory.